# Transit Gateway Attachment is getting creating without a Name Tag when calling create_vpn_connection() along with TransitGatewayId Argument

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm working on a Python script to create a [site-to-site VPN connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/SetUpVPNConnections.html) in bulk.

I have created the Customer Gateways as Step 1: of [Create a customer gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/SetUpVPNConnections.html) suggests. I'm now creating VPN Connection (Step 5: [Create a Site-to-Site VPN connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/SetUpVPNConnections.html)). I'm calling [create_vpn_connection()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_vpn_connection) with `TransitGatewayId` parameter to create a vpn connection. This creates the VPN Connection for me, ALONG WITH a Transit Gateway Attachment.

```
create_vpn_connection(CustomerGatewayId,Type,TransitGatewayId,TagSpecifications)
```

The problem is (I think) because Transit Gateway Attachment is getting created as a side effect of creating create_vpn_connection with `TransitGatewayId` parameter, the Transit Gateway Attachment does not have a Name tag.

[image]

I can create a new tag for Transit Gateway Attachment by calling: [client.create_tags()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_tags).

`client.create_tags(Tags=TAGS, Resources=[myTransitGatewayAttachmentId])`

But for that, I still need to know my `TransitGatewayAttachmentId`.

Is there a way to create "VPN Connection" along with "Transit Gateway Attachment" and its `Name` Tag?